# Windows 7 freezes at login screen/or on desktop

Tags: windows-7, freeze

When I turned my PC on today it freezes at the login screen, it seems to be time based, because if i'm quick enough to log in and get to my Desktop I can do stuff for a short time before it freezes again. Completely everything freezes, can't do input or anything - nothing updates on the screen.

When I try to boot safe-mode the log-in screen appears in a low resolution but a few seconds later Windows 7 seems to boot its self again in what appears to be "normal" mode because this time the resolution is full 1920x1080.

I'm not really sure what to do :S

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem,

I booted in normal mode, quickly opened msconfig, disabled everything from startup and restarted the PC, everything works fine now.. still not sure what program it was